# JavaFX - HTML tooltip in WebView changes z-ordering of other windows opened by the application

Tags: java, html, javafx, webview, tooltip

When you hover on an HTML element with a defined "*title*" attribute that has been rendered in a JavaFX **WebView** object a tooltip displaying the text defined in the title is displayed.

The problem occurs when other windows that have been opened by the application are positioned on top of the window containing the webview, in this case, the window containing the webview is brought to the top while the other windows are sent to the background and become completely or partially hidden depending on their position relative to the window containing the webview. The following code sample demonstrated the issue:

Java code:

```
package javaFXSandbox;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Node;

import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;

import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ToolTipBug extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {

            stage.setTitle("Web View");

            String htmlUrlStr = getClass().getResource("/resources/toolTipBug.html").toExternalForm();

            WebView webView = new WebView();
            webView.setPrefHeight(400);
            System.out.println("Preferred Height: " + webView.getPrefHeight());
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

            webEngine.load(htmlUrlStr);

            VBox root = new VBox(2);
            ObservableList<Node> vBoxChildren = root.getChildren();

            vBoxChildren.add(webView);

            Button button = new Button("Open a Popup");
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Opening a popup");
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    Label label = new Label("Hello World");
                    label.setPrefWidth(400);
                    label.setPrefHeight(300);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(label);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
                }
            });
            vBoxChildren.add(button);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/toolTipSandbox.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:800px; height:600px; background-color:lightgrey">
        <div style="height:70px; width: 70px; background-color: salmon; padding:12px; border:1px solid black;" title="ToolTip">
            Hover Here
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Obviously this isn't the cause of your issue, but your demo code is missing import statements for ActionEvent and EventHandler.

Comment: This is definitely a bug.  I can't find any existing mention of it in the Java Bug Database, so you may want to submit one.